# Append ASCII symbol to the string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string and an ASCII code in hex `0x1111`.
How can I append ASCII code at the end/beginning of the string to see the symbol of this code?

```
NSString* some = @"some";
```

Comment: 0x1111 is not an ASCII code. ASCII codes are from 0x00 to 0x7f only. Please clarify what you actually have.

Comment: What kind of ASCII value is that? ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. `0x1111` is two bytes.

Comment: not getting your problem

Comment: My mistake, not ascii symbol.  but i need to append `0x1111` to `@"some`.

Comment: 0x1111 is meaningless. You need to know what encoding it is. If it's not ASCII, then what is it?

Comment: In special characters menu you can see what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
NSString *some = @"some";
some = [[@"@\u1111" stringByAppendingString:some] stringByAppendingString:@"@\u1111"];
NSLog(@"Some: %@", some);
```

returns:

```
Some: @ᄑsome@ᄑ
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the `NSString`s are immutable – you need to make an `NSMutableString` to append things. The `mutableCopy` method is handy for this.

`NSMutableString`’s `appendFormat:` or `appendString:` method can append to the end. Format strings are similar to the traditional `printf(3)` C function (with the addition of `%@` for inserting Obj-C objects).

```
NSString *some = @"some";
char newCharacter = 0x41;
NSString *stringWithCharacter = [[some mutableCopy] appendFormat:@"%c", newCharacter];
```

Another way is to create a new `NSString` from a format string. This is probably the easiest.

```
NSString *some = @"some";
NSString *stringWithPrependedCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@", 0x41, some];
```

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed in the comments `0x1111` is not an ASCII character, but much more likely a UTF-16 character.

You can create a new `NSString` from the original string and the character string:

```
NSString *some = @"some";
NSString *combined = [some stringByAppendingString:@"\u1111"];
```

or you could append it to an `NSMutableString`:

```
NSString *some = @"some";
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString new];
[str appendString:some];
[str appendString:@"\u1111"];
```

If the character varies, then you can convert it from a character to an `NSString` object using:

```
unichar input = 0x1111;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&input
                                        length:1];
```

and append it as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below method

**For appending data in beginning:**

```
NSString *some = @"some";
char newCharacter = 0x41;
NSString *some = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%c%@",newCharacter,some];
```

**For appending data in end:**

```
NSString *some = @"some";
char newCharacter = 0x41;
NSString *some = [NSString stringwithformat:@"%@%c",some,newCharacter];
```